# Jest + React: Mocking props in a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

So I haven't tried Jest before too much with React and was curious from the start how to test some things.

For example: I have a sorting function:

```
sortFunction = cellDataKey => {
  let changeSortDirection;

  const {
    sortBy,
    sortDirection,
    dataSource
  } = this.props;

  if (cellDataKey === sortBy) {
  ....
```

And I'm curious how to test something like this, should I mock the `props`? Or somehow refactor the following function?

Thank you!(:

Answer (score 0):

If your function doesn't have side effects nor external dependencies, as it seems, it's quite easy. You just call the function with test data and compare the returned value to the expected value, like this (assuming the function is exported and isolated in its own file):

```
// Let's call this file sortFunction.test.js
import sortFunction from './sortFunction'

describe('A function to sort them all', () => {
  test('It returns sorted values', () => {
    let myTestData = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    expect(sortFunction(myTestData)).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  })
})
```

Once you run the test with `jest`, the test will fail or pass and you'll see the output.

**UPDATE:**

How to use the function from a component (usually you would put the function and other utilities in some dedicated folder, like `lib` or `util`):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import sortFunction from './sortFunction'

class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            values: sortFunction(this.state.values)
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            { this.state.values.map(value => (
                <div>{value}</div>
            )) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Table
```

Comment: But for example, if the `sortFunction` need data, which is from `Table` component props, how would I tackle this?

Comment: You mean how would you use the function from the `Table` component, or how to test it _with_ the component?

Comment: Both options would be interesting to hear, but first I thought about the first one

Comment: Check the addition above.